# Change Form 1 Label value using UserControl Window Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to windows Forms and didn't know about user control. I have a form 1 with a label and want to change the value of the label using user control. I also called user control in form1. I tested the form function using the usercontrol_click event. It shows the message box but not changing the label value.

Form 1 user control name flowLayoutPanel1
user control name ListView

```cs
private void ListItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 a = new Form1();
    //a.emailbody();
    a.label5.Text = "work";
}
```

```cs
public void emailbody()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
}
```

Comment: Raise an event.  The form can subscribe it and update the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new form with `Form1 a = new Form1();` in the click event handler, but you never show this form using `a.Show();` or `a.ShowDialog()`.

Did you intend to set the label on the current form? If yes, then don't create a new form.

```cs
private void ListItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Uses label in this form:
    label5.Text = "work";
}
```

You simply write `emailbody();` to call a method on the current form.

---

If you intended to set the label on another form that was already open, you need a reference to this form. E.g. you can store it in a field in the current form

```cs
private Form1 _form1;

private void OpenOtherFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _form1 = new Form1();
    _form1.Show();
}

private void ListItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_form1 is not null) {
        _form1.label5.Text = "work";
    }
}
```

---

If you want to change the label of your user control, the label must be public. Assuming that the user control is on your form, do something like this:

```cs
myUserControl.label5.Text = "work";
```

If it is on another form, the user control must be public as well:

```cs
_form1.myUserControl.label5.Text = "work";
```

if the user control is on the panel:

```cs
flowLayoutPanel1.myUserControl.label5.Text = "work";
```

---

If the user control is on the same form as where the label is and `ListItem_Click` is in the user control, then you must get reference to the form first.

```cs
// In the user control
var form1 = FindForm() as Form1;
if (form1 is not null) {
    form1.label5.Text = "work";
}
```

Comment: Form 1
label5 Text CurrentStatus

UserControl
form1.label5.text = "Work";

Output Require
label5 Text Work

When I am doing, it is not updating the value.

Comment: I don't understand. Please use an [online-translator](https://translate.google.com/) to write the text in your language and translate it to English.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes The event is generated in an UserControl. The OP wants to set the Text of a Label (but, probably, do something else with some data coming from the UC), child of the Parent Form, when this event is raised. The OP should expose a custom event with custom EventArgs, to pass whatever data it holds / generates to subscribers of the event

Comment: In Form 1 label5 Text is CurrentStatus. With the help of UserControl, I am trying form1.label5.text = "Work"; I want to set label5 text value to Work.

Comment: Is the user control on the same form where the label is? And is `ListItem_Click` in the user control?

Comment: Full Scenario - Created a custom listview using UserControl which has 2-3 labels. Accessed UserControl in Form1 using FlowLayoutpanel. Form1 also contains some labels. I want to change form1 label text value when click on listview item. I am trying to display a list, when click on list, other container will display it's value.

Comment: Yes. User control on the same form.